# Select CheckBox in Selenium Webdriver 2

Tags: selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

New to Selenium, trying to learn from online videos and discussion board.

I need to select a checkbox on the site, here is the HTML code.

```
<tr class="ms-test-List-Row" otypename="shopping" otype="10148" oid="{4D1A1C1B-DA33-414E-91D9-6202B0F71A6A}">
<td align="center" class="ms-test-List-NonDataCell">
<input tabindex="0" class="ms-test-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{4D1A1C1B-DA33-414E-91D9-6202B0F71A6A}" type="checkbox"/>
```

I tried using the:

```
dri.findElement(By.id("checkBox_{4D1A1C1B-DA33-414E-91D9-6202B0F71A6A}")).click();
```

but it's unable to locate this.

Any other method I should be using for this.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, instead of adding your code in comments, can you just edit it into your question?

Comment: @user_in_ca I copied your html and test with your code 'dri.findElement(By.id("checkBox_{4D1A1C1B-DA33-414E-91D9-6202B0F71A6A}")).click()" . It is working perfectly fine. It locate and select Checkbox. No issue  at all, do check again !!!

Comment: @gitsitgo - I apologies, this is my first post on the site. I didn't see edit button but maybe I had to refresh the page after posting.

Comment: @aberry - I just tried it again dre.findElement(By.id("checkBox_{4D1A1C1B-DA33-414E-91D9-6202B0F71A6A}")).click();    and it's failing. Here is the error. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == checkBox_{4D1A1C1B-DA33-414E-91D9-6202B0F71A6A}

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that ID is a GUID that is generated at runtime.  If you view the page when it is launched by Selenium, does the checkbox you wish to access have the same ID?

Comment: @Richard - Yes it does have the same ID. I also tried with the partial ID Checkbox_ as suggested by alecxe but that didn't work either.

Comment: If the id is same and still getting the error i would say that please check whether your chkbox is contained in a frame/ iframe or modal dialog...

Answer (score 0):

As Vivek Singh suggested it was inside the iframe, I switched the frame and was able to find the checkbox element. 
Thank you all for your time and suggestions! Really appreciate it.